# NSIS: how to load different License file based on selected language

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I try to make a NSIS installator with Electron-Builder. I need to show different license files based on selected language by user.

*package.json*

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "22.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0"
  },

"build": {
    
    "directories": {
      "output": "out"
    },

    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "images/logo.ico"
    },

    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "uninstallerIcon": "images/logo.ico",
      "installerIcon": "images/logo.ico",

      "displayLanguageSelector": true,
      "installerLanguages": ["en_US", "bg_BG"],
      "multiLanguageInstaller": true,

      "perMachine": true,
      "include": "build/preInstall.nsh"
    }
  }
}
```

*preInstall.nsh*

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE $(translatedlicensefile)
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
LicenseLangString translatedlicensefile ${LANG_ENGLISH} "build/license/license_en.txt"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE Bulgarian
LicenseLangString translatedlicensefile ${LANG_BULGARIAN} "build/license/license_bg.txt"
```

get this error:

```
Error output:
LicenseLangString: open failed "build/license/license_en.txt"
Usage: LicenseLangString name lang_id|0 license_path
!include: error in script: "/Users/..../preInstall.nsh" on line 32
Error in script "<stdin>" on line 51 -- aborting creation process
```

line 32 is

```
LicenseLangString translatedlicensefile ${LANG_ENGLISH} "build/license/license_en.txt"
```

I try many examples including the official one and think using electron builder messed up the flow of NSIS scripts and i can't include any modification at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to load the license files directly into NSIS code. Its not a good practice, but still looking for better solution.

*node_modules/app-builder-lib/out/targets/nsis/nsisLicense.js*

```
const licenseFiles = await license_1.getLicenseFiles(packager);
// --> workaround
let license_bg = {file: packager.projectDir + "/pages/license_bg.txt", lang:"bg", langWithRegion:"bg_BG", langName:"Bulgarian"};
let license_en = {file: packager.projectDir + "/pages/license_en.txt", lang:"en", langWithRegion:"en_US", langName:"English"};
licenseFiles.push(license_el);
licenseFiles.push(license_en);
// <-- workaround
// if (licenseFiles.length === 0) {
//     return;
// }
```